What are "rent and waistline parties"?
Speaking of the joy that he sometimes felt in gatherings of Black people, James Baldwin writes:

Perhaps we were, all of us—pimps, whores, racketeers, church members, and children—bound together by the nature of our oppression, the specific and peculiar complex of risks we had to run; if so, within these limits we sometimes achieved with each other a freedom that was close to love. I remember, anyway, church suppers and outings, and, later, after I left the church, rent and waistline parties where rage and sorrow sat in the darkness and did not stir, and we ate and drank and talked and laughed and danced and forgot all about "the man." We had the liquor, the chicken, the music, and each other, and had no need to pretend to be what we were not.
Baldwin, James. "Down at the Cross: Letter from a Region of my Mind." 1962. The Fire Next Time. 1963. New York: Modern Library, 1995. pp. 13–105. Quotation is from pp. 40–41, emphasis added. 

What are rent and waistline parties?

Rent Party

A rent party (sometimes called a house party) is a social occasion where tenants hire a musician or band to play and pass the hat to raise money to pay their rent, originating in Harlem during the 1920s. These parties were a means for Black tenants to eat, dance, and get away from everyday hardship and discrimination.1 The rent party played a major role in the development of jazz and blues music, alongside forms of swing dancing.2 The Oxford English Dictionary states that the term skiffle means "rent party", indicating the informality of the occasion. Thus, the word became associated with informal music. However, many notable jazz musicians are associated with rent parties, including pianists Speckled Red, Georgia Tom, Little Brother Montgomery,2 James P. Johnson, Willie "the Lion" Smith, and Fats Waller, although rent parties also featured bands as well. The OED also gives boogie as a term meaning 'rent party'.

Waistline Party

Some DARE words hint at long-lost social occasions. At a “waistline party,” mentioned in African-American circles, the price of admission corresponded to a reveler’s girth...

Waistline parties possibly invented by Ralph Mercado.

In his early teens, he was "completely blown away" after seeing the Machito Orchestra perform at the Palladium, and he left "knowing I had to be involved in this music somehow, personally involved".1 Lacking any musical skill as a singer or performer, he started promoting "waistline parties", live music events in apartment building basements in which women were charged in proportion to their waist size, with thinner women charged less, and Mercado measuring at the door.1

Description is a little ambiguous, he promoted them, but it isn't totally clear that he invented them.
